# Javascript es6 - is it reassigning or a parameter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6

Can someone please explain what's happening here? I know these are middleware for express, I'm looking at the syntax.

I understand the es6 syntax for `mustBeLoggedIn` but I'm not sure what `const forbidden = message => (req, res, next) => {` is doing. Is `message` another parameter that comes before req, res, next? If so, why isn't it in the parenthesis? I originally  thought this was just assigning another variable name to the function. So I could call it either `forbidden()` or `message()`, no? But looking at how it's being used it looks more like a parameter...

Another interesting thing I noticed is that the middleware `forbidden` is being invoked in the get request and `mustBeLoggedIn` is only being passed and not invoked. Why?

```js
   const mustBeLoggedIn = (req, res, next) => {
      if (!req.user) {
        return res.status(401).send('You must be logged in')
      }
      next()
    }

    const forbidden = message => (req, res, next) => {
      res.status(403).send(message)
    }

module.exports = require('express').Router()
 .get('/', forbidden('only admins can list users'), (req, res, next) => 
  User.findAll()
  .then(users => res.json(users))
  .catch(next))
 .post('/', (req, res, next) =>
  User.create(req.body)
  .then(user => res.status(201).json(user))
  .catch(next))
 .get('/:id', mustBeLoggedIn, (req, res, next) => 
  User.findById(req.params.id)
  .then(user => res.json(user))
  .catch(next))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dislike this use of the ES6 syntax as it obscures the meaning of the code only in the interest of brevity.  The best code is not always the shortest possible way to write it.  Give people tools and they will sometimes use them inappropriately.

`forbidden()` is a function that takes one argument `message` that returns a middleware handler that uses that one argument.  So, it's a way of making a customized middleware handler that has a parameter pre-built-in.  When you call `forbidden(msg)`, it returns a middleware handler function which you can then use as middleware.

The ES5 way of writing this (ignoring for a moment the difference in `this` which would be different, but is not used here) would look like this:

```
const forbidden = function(message) {
   return function(req, res, next) {
       res.status(403).send(message);
   }
}
```

So, when you call `forbidden(someMsg)`, you get back a function that can be used as middleware.

> If so, why isn't it in the parenthesis?

With the ES6 arrow syntax, a single argument does not have to be in parentheses.  Only multiple arguments require parentheses.

> Another interesting thing I noticed is that the middleware `forbidden` is being invoked in the get request

This is because invoking it returns the actual middleware function so you have to execute to get the return value which is then passed as the middleware.

> and mustBeLoggedIn is only being passed and not invoked. Why?

Because it's already a middleware function, so you just want to pass a reference to it, not invoke it yet.

---

FYI, this route:

```
.get('/', forbidden('only admins can list users'), (req, res, next) => 
    User.findAll()
    .then(users => res.json(users))
    .catch(next))
```

does not make sense to me based on the code you've shown because `forbidden()` will return a middleware that will ALWAYS return a 403 response and will not allow the next handler to get called.  This would only make sense to me if `forbidden()` had logic in it to check if the current user is actually an admin or not (which you don't show).

Comment: @AnnaGarcia - I added answers to more of your questions.

Comment: Thank you so much! I did notice that about forbidden always returning 403 and was wondering why but forgot to ask that too, so thanks for answering that as well haha. I guess that must be a mistake in the code since I didn't write it.